# How to draw Small Path with curve SVG

Tags: svg, charts, path

how to draw a small path with a curve, this is the code i've tried.

Straight Path

```
<path d="M0,6 H30" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
```

Curved path with the same length

```
<path d="M0,6 Q5,10 15,H30" stroke="#333" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
```

the curved path is not working

Comment: For the Q command you need 4 values. You have only 3

Comment: On top of that a comma is only allowed to separate two numbers so 15, H is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply 4 parameters for the quadratic curve operator Q. You only supply 3 parameters and you should remove the commas - not that you can't use commas, but they can cause bugs if you use them wrong. Here is an example that draws a quadratic curve and a straight line between the curve's start- and end points:

```
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 10 80 Q 95 10 180 80 H 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

See the [SVG Path Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and search for *quadratic curve*.

Answer (score 0):

`Q` path commands need to have two sets of coordinates after them. That means four numbers. Your path only has three numbers.